# iterate through a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying extract top words from a topic model and print the words as follows

```
test_topic = [(0, [('pizza', 0.13345005), ('notch', 0.08421454), ('weekend', 0.049728252), ('fair', 0.035808913), ('thank', 0.034821175), ('girlfriend', 0.03274733), ('seen', 0.029821698), ('patient', 0.026760893), ('sucked', 0.026622303), ('skip', 0.026458882), ('san', 0.024171583), ('luckily', 0.021163197), ('god', 0.020423584), ('stellar', 0.016307), ('improve', 0.01599736)]),(1, [('ingredients', 0.019390099), ('opening', 0.018882414), ('choice', 0.013553904), ('summer', 0.01068847), ('minute', 0.010665418), ('asian', 0.010231626), ('money', 0.010114605), ('near', 0.00918076), ('dined', 0.008954125), ('odd', 0.0087335445), ('14', 0.008653159), ('noise', 0.008145982), ('place', 0.008041287), ('live', 0.0075712656), ('definitely', 0.007468632)]),(2, [('pork', 0.022275768), ('chicken', 0.022122012), ('ribs', 0.021125246), ('strips', 0.018241541), ('green', 0.014933401), ('tomato', 0.013756915), ('cheese', 0.013535802), ('juice', 0.012698732), ('soup', 0.012126858), ('good', 0.011680452), ('sauce', 0.011264608), ('grilled', 0.010635098), ('favorite', 0.010507565), ('fat', 0.009539875), ('meat', 0.009525091)])]

for i, item in enumerate(test_topic):
    for weight, term in item:
        print(term)
```

However, I get this error

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Though `print(item)` returns

> 0
>   [('pizza', 0.13345005), ('notch', 0.08421454), ('weekend', 0.049728252), ('fair', 0.035808913), ('thank', 0.034821175), ('girlfriend', 0.03274733), ('seen', 0.029821698), ('patient', 0.026760893), ('sucked', 0.026622303), ('skip', 0.026458882), ('san', 0.024171583), ('luckily', 0.021163197), ('god', 0.020423584), ('stellar', 0.016307), ('improve', 0.01599736)]

`print(type(item))` returns **int**

Can anyone throw some light on where I'm going wrong?

Edit:

The context of the problem is to extract topics from a yelp review corpus. I'm using [LdaModel.show_topics](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.show_topics)  to give me topic distributions and from those I want to understand the top terms. So what i get is actually a `list of {str, tuple of (str, float)}`.

Comment: the first item in your tuple is an integer (`0`) and you can not iterate with `for` on it.

Comment: How about `for weight, term in test_topic[1]:`?

Comment: `test_topic` is a tuple already. Enumerate on `test_topic[1]`. It should probably work.

Comment: Austin and Praveenkumar : I've to go over a list of tuples. I'll update my question to give more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first item in `test_topic` is `0`, which is an `int`. You cannot iterate over it.

If I understand correctly, you have the following nested collection:

```
(0, [(t1, w1), (t2, w2)...])
        ^ you want ^ these
```

Accordingly, you should skip the first element (the `0`), which gives you a one-element `tuple` containing a `list` of `(term, weight)` `tuples`. You can then take that one element and iterate through it:

```
for i, (term, weight) in enumerate(test_topic[1:][0]):
    # Note that you don't actually use i here...
    print(term)
```

Output:

```
pizza
notch
weekend
fair
thank
girlfriend
seen
patient
sucked
skip
san
luckily
god
stellar
improve
```

Answer (score 0):

You get it because the first element in your list is zero:

```
for i, item in enumerate(test_topic[1:]):
```

Answer (score 0):

You're enumerating a `tuple`, so your first `item` is `0`.

Now you can't do this:

```
weight, term = 0
```

Because you need a tuple like `('pizza', 0.13345005)` so you can do this:

```
weight, term = ('pizza', 0.13345005)
```

You didn't mention what your desired output is, but I'm not entirely sure you need `enumarate`!

And the order seems odd, shouldn't it be `term, weight`?

So we can do this:

```
test_topic = (
    0, 
    [
        ('pizza', 0.13345005), 
        ('notch', 0.08421454), 
        ('weekend', 0.049728252),
        ...
    ]
)

for item in test_topic[1]:
    term, weight = item
    print(term, weight)
output:
pizza 0.13345005
notch 0.08421454
weekend 0.049728252
...
```

You actually don't need `item` here, you can simply write:

```
for term, weight in test_topic[1]:
    print(term, weight)
```

However, if you do need `enumerate` (for some reason that you haven't mentioned), you can do it like this:

```
for i, item in enumerate(test_topic[1]):
    term, weight = item
    print(f'{i}. The weight of {term} is {weight}')

output:
0. The weight of pizza is 0.13345005
1. The weight of notch is 0.08421454
2. The weight of weekend is 0.049728252
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to do something like following

```
test_topic = [('pizza', 0.13345005), ('notch', 0.08421454), ('weekend', 0.049728252), ('fair', 0.035808913), ('thank', 0.034821175), ('girlfriend', 0.03274733), ('seen', 0.029821698), ('patient', 0.026760893), ('sucked', 0.026622303), ('skip', 0.026458882), ('san', 0.024171583), ('luckily', 0.021163197), ('god', 0.020423584), ('stellar', 0.016307), ('improve', 0.01599736)]
for i, tup in enumerate(test_topic):
    print(i ,tup[0], tup[1])
```

in your case tuple (0, [()]) -> tuple having 1st element 0 2nd element an list of tuples
so when u enumerate this in the very first pass u having 
i == 0 and item == 0